# C++ move constructor multiple calls, in std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, move

I wrote simple code in order to understand move semantics and move constructor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;



class Data
{
public:

    Data(int sz)
    {
        cout << "ctor" << endl;
        buffer = new int[sz];
        size = sz;
    }
    Data(Data& other)
    {
        size = other.size;
        cout << "copy ctor" << endl;
        buffer = new int[size];
        memcpy(buffer, other.buffer, size * sizeof(int)); //deep copy
    }
    Data(Data&& r)
    {
        size = r.size;
        cout << "move ctor" << endl;
        buffer = r.buffer;

    }

private:
    double bigValue;
    int* buffer;
    int size;

};



int main(void) 
{

    auto f = []() { cout << "---------------------\n"; };
     

    vector<Data> data;

    data.push_back(  move( Data(1)  ) ); // move constructor called once
    f();

    data.push_back(  move( Data(2)  ) ); // move constructor called twice
    f();

    data.push_back(  move( Data(3)  ) ); // move constructor called 3 times
    f();


    int stop; cin >> stop;

    return 0;
}
```

I see something strange:

every time I call push_back, another call of move constructor is performed.

program output attached

[image]

I need help understanding this bizarre output.

Thanks.

Comment: Use `data.reserve(3);` (or print `data.capacity()` before/after `push_back`) to see the change

Comment: `std::move` in `std::move( Data(1)  )` is useless.

Comment: `std::move` is just a cast to rvalue reference, and your temporaries are rvalues, so your `std::move`s make no difference.

Comment: Moreover, in the move constructor, it would be better to "clean" the "moved from" data by setting the buffer to `nullptr` and the size to `0`.

Comment: If you're constructing an object only to put it into a collection, you should probably `.emplace_back()` instead of `.push_back()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a vector grows it has to reallocate. A vector starts out with capacity 0 and only increases capacity when needed. Typically capacity is increased by factors of `2` to ensure the time complexity promised by `push_back`. Other factors are ok as well.

What you see is the vector moving the elements to different place in memory when it reallocates.

You do not see that additional moves when you allocate enough space upfront:

```
vector<Data> data;
data.reserve(5);           // <------------------- reserve
data.push_back(  move( Data(1)  ) );
f();
data.push_back(  move( Data(2)  ) );
f();
data.push_back(  move( Data(3)  ) );
f();
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/sWc4e7vYT):

```
ctor
move ctor
---------------------
ctor
move ctor
---------------------
ctor
move ctor
---------------------
```

PS: as mentioned in comments the cast via `std::move` is superfluous. You achieve the same with `data.push_back( Data(1) );`, sloppy speaking because `Data(1)` already is a temporary and `push_back` does move when it can. Moreover (also from comments), when you want to construct an element in place you should rather use `emplace_back` instead of first creating a temporary outside the vector and then moving it in. `std::move` does not hurt here, but the unnecessary temporary might be expensive depending on how costly moving the element is.